# C++, fastest STL container for recursively doing { delete[begin], insert[end], and summing entire array contents}

Tags: c++, performance, containers

I have some code and an array where each iteration I delete the first element, add an element at the end, and then sum the contents of the array. Naturally, the array stays the same size. I have tried using both vector and list, but both seem pretty slow.

```
int length = 400;

vector <int> v_int(length, z);
list <int>   l_int(length, z);

for(int q=0; q < x; q++)
{
    int sum =0;

    if(y)                       //if using vector
    {      
        v_int.erase(v_int.begin());    //takes `length` amount of time to shift memory
        v_int.push_back(z);   
        for(int w=0; w < v_int.size(); w++)
            sum += v_int[w];
    }      
    else                        //if using list
    {
        l_int.pop_front();             //constant time
        l_int.push_back(z);
        list<int>::iterator it;
        for ( it=l_int.begin() ; it != l_int.end(); it++ ) //seems to take much  
            sum += *it;                                    //longer than vector does
    }
}
```

The problem is that erasing the first element of the vector requires that each other element be shifted down, multiplying, by the size of the vector, the amount of time taken each iteration. Using a linked list avoids this (constant time removal of elements), and should not sacrifice any time summing the array (linear time traversal of the array), except that in my program it seems to be taking way longer to sum the contents than the vector does (at least 1 order of magnitude longer).

Is there a better container to use here? or a different way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efficient additions and deletions of end elements in a container is what the [deque](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/) was made for.

If you are just inserting at one end and deleting at the other then you can use a [queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/queue/)

Answer (score 7):

Why not keep a running sum with `sum -= l_int.front(); sum += z`?

Also the data structure you're looking for with that delete/insert performance is a `queue`

Comment: hey good idea. Btw, is queue faster than list for delete/insert or ~the same speed? Also, out of curiosity, what's with list being so slow for array traversal?

Comment: With a simple array you can access each element with pointer arithmetic. If you have elements of a certain size then you can just go to the `initial_offset + size * index` to find the element at the index. With a linked list you have to visit the first element, find the link to the next one, visit the next one, repeat until you get to the one you want.

Comment: @Graff yeah but if I already have to excess every element, as in summation, this shouldn't cost much extra time should it?

Comment: For a little more context, the [stl vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) is similar to a c array and the [stl list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/) is similar to a linked list.

Comment: @Matt Generally it's much faster to do the pointer arithmetic for a lookup in a vector than to get an iterator to the next element in a list. Also, a queue should be similar in speed to a list for delete/insert - perhaps a tiny bit slower but usually not by much.

Comment: @Graff, Ah, ok. I guess that's about what I figured. I just didn't expect the iterator part to take so much extra time. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is not *really* the pointer indirection - the really painful part is that list elements are scattered throughout memory (each one is individually allocated on the heap, and there is usually at least a 2-pointer overhead between heap allocations), thus the CPU cache keeps getting flushed, and you are waiting for information to crawl its way in from memory.